# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher not found when using camelahc component

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I want to call an external http service using ahc component,camel-ahc dependency is added to pom.xml, and also camel-ahc feature is installed in karaf:

```
feature:install camel-ahc
```

bundles that has been added:

camel-ahc
and 
                         wrap_file__home_ossl_.m2_repository_org_asynchttpclient_async-http-client_2.4.3_async-http-cl...

and my code is:

```
    <camelContext id="jetty-ws-camel-ahc" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
       <route id="ahc-route">
        <from uri="timer://webinar?period=20000"/> 
              <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                  <constant>GET</constant>
              </setHeader>
          <to uri="ahc:http://217.0.0.0:3030/sendSMS/mynumber/bye"/>
      <log message="message sent!"/>
       </route>
</camelContext>
```

but I have a warning and the request is not sended to http address: 
WARN [Blueprint Extender: 3] Listener caused an exception, will be ignored
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher not found by wrap_file__home_ossl_.m2_repository_org_asynchttpclient_async-http-client_2.4.3_async-http-client-2.4.3.jar_Export-Package_org.asynchttpclient.__version_2.4.3

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the automatic wrapping of the artifact `org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client`.

The wrapping by default makes all Import-Package clauses optional, which sometimes makes it hard to build a reliably wired setup because when the resolver looks at the wrapped bundle before looking at the ones exporting the "optional" packages, they will not get wired together and as they are optional, the resolver will happily skip them even if the appear a microsecond later.

To test this, you can `bundle:refresh <id>` the async-http-client bundles and have a look at `bundle:tree-show <id>` whether packages are still not wired (be marked as `WARNING`).

To reliably fix it, you can create your own feature based on the official Apache Camel feature and modify the wrapping to make certain imports mandatory (e.g. append `&Import-Package=org.reactivestreams,*;resolution:=optional` to the `wrap:` statement).

Also have a look at the [Wrap Protocol](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/paxurl/pages/3833898/Wrap+Protocol).